# R: Exclude columns with specific conditions in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, na

I'm trying to exclude some columns based on specific conditions in R. My data is a big matrix with 5000 rows and 1000 columns. It looks like that:

[image: Data example]

I would like to exclude all columns with less than an average of 100 observations per month. I tried a for loop but it returns an empty value.

Comment: Eli, please provide a way for us to reproduce your data, you can use the dput() function on your R object, then copy and paste the result on this post for that.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). You could create a small example where you have 5-8 columns and instead of 100 observation we can keep columns with only 3-4 observations.

Comment: colSums(is.na(<matrix>)) will tell you how many NAs per column.. you subset your matrix using this boolean? for example, <matrix>[,colSums(is.na(<matrix>)) < 100]

Comment: @StupidWolf Thanks you so much! That worked perfectly!

Comment: thats great. Next time try to provide an example of your data like @RonakShah pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at tibble’s as_tbble() and dplyr’s select_if() function.

Something like ...

```
months <- 3

matrix %>% as_tibble() %>% 
select_if(function (col) sum(!is.na(col)) > 100 * months )
```

See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/select_if

Comment: Thanks Daniel Lathrop! I tried it but it returns the following error: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: Right... it’s a matrix rather than a data frame. My bad. Is it ok to convert your matrix into a df? I’m editing my answer to take that approach.

Comment: I converted it into a data.table, but with that code `dt %>% select_if(function (cols) sum(!is.na(cols)) > 100 * months )`, I got 0 rows. Also I don't understand why should I assign a value to months. I have hundreds of rows for each month. The expected output is a matrix or table excluding all columns that have less than 100 observations, i.e 5000 - 100 NA observations, except the column for months. Thanks!